# Terraform S3 Bucket Object's etag keeps updating on each apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am uploading AWS Lambda code into an S3 bucket as zip files.

I have a resource declared for the S3 bucket object:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "source-code-object" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket.id}"
  key = "source-code.zip"
  source = "lambda_source_code/source-code.zip"
  etag = "${base64sha256(file("lambda_source_code/source-code.zip"))}"
}
```

I also have a data declaration to zip up my code:

```
data "archive_file" "source-code-zip" {
  type = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/lambda_source_code/run.py"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda_source_code/source-code.zip"
}
```

The `terraform apply` output keeps showing me a change to the hash:

```
  ~ aws_s3_bucket_object.source-code-object
      etag: "old_hash" => "new_hash"
```

Even though nothing in my source code has changed. Why is this behavior occurring? I've seen [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662244/terraform-lambda-source-code-hash-update-with-same-code) with Lambdas' source codes continually changing, but my Lambdas actually are not updating each time (checked in console the last update time). However, it does look like a new S3 bucket object is uploaded on every `apply`.

Answer (score 15):

It's possible that your S3 bucket uses a KMS key to apply encryption by default. When configured that way, the `etag` is not an MD5 of the file content ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Object.html)).

> Objects created by the PUT Object, POST Object, or Copy operation, or through the AWS Management Console, and are encrypted by SSE-C or SSE-KMS, have ETags that are not an MD5 digest of their object data.

Without knowing their hashing implementation, there's not a way to pre-compute the value for terraform and make it a stable plan.

Instead, you should use the [`source_hash`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object#source_hash) property to address the limitation.

Answer (score 6):

To prevent an update on each apply, using the new `aws_s3_object` resource, you can use the `output_base64sha256` attribute reference.

> The aws_s3_bucket_object data source is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version! Use aws_s3_object instead, where new features and fixes will be added.

```
data "archive_file" "source-code-zip" {
  type = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/lambda_source_code/run.py"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda_source_code/source-code.zip"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "source-code-object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my-bucket.id
  key    = "source-code.zip"

  # we can also reference `output_path` from `archive_file`
  # so as not to repeat the path
  source      = data.archive_file.source-code-zip.output_path
  source_hash = data.archive_file.source-code-zip.output_base64sha256
}
```

`output_base64sha256` has the added benefit of working with s3 objects encrypted using KMS, as @Matt F pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

Zip archives contain metadata by default, such as timestamps, which results in the hash being different even if the source files are not. When manually building the archive you can avoid this with the `--no-extra` or `-X` flag. I am not sure if Terraform supports this flag.

From the zip man page:

> -X
>
> Do not save extra file attributes (Extended Attributes on  OS/2, uid/gid  and  file  times  on  Unix).  The zip format uses extra
> fields to include additional information for each  entry.   Some extra
> fields are specific to particular systems while others are applicable
> to all systems.  Normally when zip reads entries from an  existing
> archive, it reads the extra fields it knows, strips the rest, and adds
> the extra fields applicable to  that  system. With -X, zip strips all
> old fields and only includes the Unicode and Zip64 extra fields
> (currently these two extra fields  cannot be disabled).
>
> Negating  this  option,  -X-,  includes  all  the  default extra
> fields, but also copies over any unrecognized extra fields.

Answer (score -1):

I replaced `etag` with `source_hash` https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object#source_hash and finally got:

```
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
```

The hash is stored in tf state not aws. Like it says in the docs:

```
Triggers updates like etag but useful to address etag encryption limitations. Set using filemd5("path/to/source") (Terraform 0.11.12 or later). (The value is only stored in state and not saved by AWS.)
```