# How to create a hash consistent python dependency .zip

Tags: python, aws-lambda, continuous-deployment, terraform-provider-aws

All my terraform planning *since ever* triggers a replacement of a dependency code Lambda Layer on every push even with my `poetry.lock` file not changing. **Is there a way to create a folder that will always look the same — have the same `base64sha256` — when downloading Python dependencies?**

To frame the issue better, this is what I always get on `terraform plan`. If you also had this problem this will look familiar:

```
  # aws_lambda_layer_version.dependencies_layer must be replaced
+/- resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "dependencies_layer" {
      ~ arn                         = "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:REDACTED:layer:REDACTED:74" -> (known after apply)
      ~ created_date                = "2021-09-23T22:20:17.910+0000" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                          = "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:REDACTED:layer:REDACTED:74" -> (known after apply)
      ~ layer_arn                   = "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:REDACTED:layer:REDACTED" -> (known after apply)
      + signing_job_arn             = (known after apply)
      + signing_profile_version_arn = (known after apply)
      ~ source_code_hash            = "Af3BfEOzwufMnD8x+yYk8v8FoqjiuP2C9jrLtS3m/nk=" -> "AzkTkha5+6cD1R9ppYv6k8vJA7FDGnCJ33gblm+jS8U=" # forces replacement
      ~ source_code_size            = 15363733 -> (known after apply)
      ~ version                     = "74" -> (known after apply)
```

I managed to fix the main source code lambda replacement with the help of the [Terraform lambda source_code_hash update with same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662244/terraform-lambda-source-code-hash-update-with-same-code) question and applied it to this Lambda Layer. But had no success:

```terraform
data "archive_file" "dependencies_layer" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "../build/dependencies_layer/"
  output_path = "../build/dependencies_layer.zip"
}


resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "dependencies_layer" {
  layer_name          = "${var.service_name}-${var.stage}-dependencies-layer"
  description         = "Python requirements lambda layer for ${var.service_name} ${var.stage} stage."
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.9"]
  filename            = data.archive_file.dependencies_layer.output_path
  source_code_hash    = data.archive_file.dependencies_layer.output_base64sha256
}
```

This makes me think that the creation of that folder is not downloading (and building?) the same files all the time. How do you manage to make this to be a hashable `.zip`? Are there some files that can be deleted that are making this happen? Today my creation of the dependency_layer folder is quite simple and looks like this:

```makefile
build/requirements.txt: build poetry.lock
    poetry export -f requirements.txt --output build/requirements.txt

build/dependencies_layer: build build/requirements.txt
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 poetry run pip install -r build/requirements.txt -t build/dependencies_layer/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ --upgrade -q
```

Edit: For clarification, the dependencies are locked with `==` versioning:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.9"
python-dateutil = "==2.8.2"
fastapi = "==0.68.1"
dependencies = "==7.1.0"
mangum = "==0.12.2"
aiodynamo = {version = "==21.9", extras = ["aiohttp"]}
pydantic = "==1.8.2"
aiohttp = "==3.7.4"
yarl = "==1.6.3"
```

Edit 2:
When I apply this plan it replace the layer but at the AWS console it do not save the old version. So it adds the `74` but there is no `73` after the apply.

Comment: do you have minor version pinning in place/exact versions set?

Comment: Yes, @PaulCollingwood. All my dependencies are managed with `==` locks and this happens on deploys in the same 4 minutes range, so I don't think someone managed to update libs all the times. I will put the dependencies on the question.

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671437/only-create-new-archive-file-for-lambda-when-code-changes/73676194#73676194