# Only create new archive_file for Lambda when code changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, github-actions, hcl

I am writing a Lambda function in TypeScript. When running `terraform apply` in `github actions` I want to build the Lambda (which requires installing the dependencies and then webpacking everything), zip it and then deploy it to AWS. The trigger for the `null_resource` used to be a timestamp, but this meant that it was doing all these steps (build, zip, deploy) even when nothing changed.

So I changed the trigger to a hash of all the files in the lambda subdirectory

```
resource "null_resource" "build_lambda_function" {
  triggers = {
    # timestamp = timestamp()
    dir_sha1 = sha1(join("", [for f in fileset(path.root, "${local.lambda_path_prefix}/${var.lambda_dir}/**"): filesha1(f)]))
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "npm ci && npm run build"
    working_dir = "${local.lambda_path_prefix}/${var.lambda_dir}"
  }
}
```

This is how I create the zip and deploy it

```
data "archive_file" "lambda_function_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${local.lambda_path_prefix}/${var.lambda_dir}/dist"
  output_path = "${local.lambda_path_prefix}/${var.lambda_dir}.zip"
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.build_lambda_function
  ]
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  function_name    = var.lambda_name
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_function_zip.output_base64sha256
  filename         = data.archive_file.lambda_function_zip.output_path
  ...
}
```

This worked great the first time I run it on gh-actions (because the null resource was triggered) but on the second run it failed. Since there was no change the lambda was not being built. No `dist` folder was created and therefore `archive_file` threw an error

> error archiving directory: could not archive missing directory: ./../lambda/testlambda/dist

Is what I want even possible?

Comment: Most CICD systems I've used just rebuilt the lambda artifacts each time.  There is a way to cache things in GH Actions, perhaps you could configure it to cache the dist folder if you don't want to rebuild it each time.
https://github.com/actions/cache

https://github.com/actions/cache

Answer (score 4):

Archive file will look in your local filesystem and run every time you do a terraform plan. Having a `depends_on` does nothing, other than saying do the archive after the `null_resource`. If `null_resource` isn't triggered, it will still say "okay, I'm done!" and your `archive_file` will run.

As the comment above has mentioned, most people rebuild every time using a trigger such as `timestamp()`. As Engineers/Developers we want the following:

```
Only build and deploy my lambda if code has changed, otherwise I don't want to waste time watching this happen.
```

To achieve this outcome we must create a persistent data store.

There are a few solutions...

1. Use Docker images for Lambda. I haven't tested this but technically it should work because you'll just push a new image and your lambda will constantly look for `latest`. [Here's an example](https://hands-on.cloud/terraform-deploy-python-lambda-container-image/#h-terraform-code) I've managed to find. Whether `latest` is good or not when it comes to image tags...that's another topic. In this case ECR is your persistent data store.
2. Manually re-create everything `archive_file` is doing using Bash or similar. Here is a working example.

lambda.tf

```
data "aws_s3_object" "s3_archive" {
  bucket = "mybucket"
  key    = "lambda/build.zip"
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.build  # wait until our upload script is done
  ]
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  function_name    = "Pokemon"
  s3_bucket        = "mybucket"
  s3_key           = "lambda/build.zip"
  source_code_hash = data.aws_s3_object.s3_archive.metadata.Sha # this is our custom metadata tag which has the same value as data.archive_file.lambda_function_zip.output_base64sha256 would have
  runtime          = "python3.9"
  handler          = "handler.handler"
  role             = aws_iam_role.role.arn
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.build # don't make lambda until after our upload.sh script
  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "build" {
  triggers = {
    requirements = filesha256("./requirements.txt") # change this file, we run script
    source_code  = filesha256("./handler.py") # change this file, we run script
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./upload.sh" # run upload.sh script
    interpreter = [
      "bash", "-c"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name = "lambda_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

handler.py (I know you're using Node, but putting it here anyways)

```
import requests


def handler(event, context):
    r = requests.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').json()
    print(r)
    return "Hello World!"
```

This is where it gets a bit nasty, Bash on Windows makes my life hard...

upload.sh

```
mkdir -p ./build # create build directory
cp handler.py ./build # copy handler.py code to build directory
cp requirements.txt ./build # copy requirements.txt code to build directory (this is like your package.json)
pip install --target ./build -r requirements.txt # this is like your npm install command (install dependencies into build directory)
'C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe' a -r build.zip ./build/* # I'm on windows so cannot use `zip` like Linux/Mac but basically .zip the entire build directory
# On Linux/Mac you can use zip -r -q build.zip ./build/*
SHA=$(sha256sum build.zip | cut -f1 -d \ | xxd -r -p | base64) # Generate a sha256 base64 encoded string (this is what lambda requires based on TF docs)
echo $SHA # Echo for debugging purposes

# Copy .zip to s3 and append metadata `sha` including our sha256 base64 encoded value so we can use it
# to detect if the .zip differs to what our Lambda function has as it's source_code_hash
aws s3 cp ./build.zip s3://mybucket/lambda/build.zip --metadata sha=$SHA
```

After doing a plan and apply this is my metadata on the build.zip in S3

[image]

And this is my Lambda terraform state:

[image]

Now when I run another terraform plan:

```
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
```

When I edit requirements.txt or my python source code (there's S3 changes but I left those out of my screenshot):

[image]

Run terraform apply:
[image]

Run a follow up terraform plan after deleting **ALL** build files from my desktop cause why not:

```
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
```

Obviously this is quite an extreme solution so if you don't mind rebuilding build assets every time then just use the `archive_file` data source. If it's a deal breaker, use what I've written above - I'm not aware of any other solutions and every GitHub issue I've seen has been "sorry, that's just the way it is" for now.

**EDIT**:
Just to add to my answer, you can avoid using S3 all together and calculate the SHA inside Terraform by following the Lambda docs

```
  # The filebase64sha256() function is available in Terraform 0.11.12 and later
  # For Terraform 0.11.11 and earlier, use the base64sha256() function and the file() function:
  # source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("lambda_function_payload.zip"))}"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("lambda_function_payload.zip")
```

`filebase64sha256` **requires the .zip to be present** prior to running Terraform though. You'd want to pull this from a persistent store such as Artifactory/S3/Hard Drive though, I believe a fresh .zip won't work.

You'd still do the archiving and zipping using a bash/python script **prior** to running Terraform but can avoid S3 with this method.

**EDIT 2**

You may be able to use a Terraform data source as well:

```
data "external" "build_archive" {
  program = ["python3", "/scripts/build_archive.py"]

  query = {
    directory = "./my_source_code"
    name      = "my_source_code"
  }
}
```

It looks like .zip archives [remember the date and time as metadata so their SHA is ever changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714139/why-does-zipping-the-same-content-twice-gives-two-files-with-different-sha1). Perhaps data source is not possible but I'll leave this here to spark further investigation from others.

With my attempt I had the data resource returning a calculated `sha` but experienced continual drift even using `.tar.gz` archives with metadata excluded. Lambda couldn't upload `.tar.gz` so I assume AWS re-calculated the SHA using my `.zip` archive and ignored my `source_code_hash` value. If I Sha'd the .tar.gz in isolation it remained consistent though.

Again, this isn't using a persistent data store so that's likely the issue.